# I have trouble calculating average typing rate (characters per min)

Tags: java, android

I have trouble calculating average typing rate (characters per min). 
Sometimes the number is too small sometimes the number is too big.
When I run it on emulator the number comes out very small;
when I run it on my phone the number comes out very large.
Please help.

```
package com.example.typeit;

import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView test, min;
EditText input;
long startTime;
double sTime, tTime;
boolean isStarted;
//ProgressBar progressBar;
int count;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    min = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.min);
    //progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);

    input.setOnKeyListener(keyListener);
    isStarted = true;
    count = 0;
}

View.OnKeyListener keyListener = new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == event.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (isStarted) {
                sTime = new Date().getTime();
                isStarted = false;
                return false;
            }
            //if(keyCode == event.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT) return false;
            if (Character.isUpperCase(input.getText().charAt(count))) {
                if (input.getText().toString().charAt(count) != keyCode + 36) {
                    min.setText("");
                } else {
                    min.setText("");
                }
            } else if (Character.isLowerCase(input.getText().charAt(count))) {
                if (input.getText().toString().charAt(count) != keyCode + 68) {
                    min.setText("");
                } else {
                    min.setText("");
                }
            }
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) count--;
            else count++;

            tTime = (new Date().getTime() - sTime) / 1000 / 60;

            int result = (int) (count / tTime);
            if (result < 0) result = 0;
            //      progressBar.setProgress(result);
            if (count == input.getText().toString().length()) {
                input.setText("");
                min.setText("" + result);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android emulator is known to be extremely slow. So measuring typing rate will not be accurate on it.

Next I'd strongly suggest to extract the measuring of the typing rate from the rest of the handling. In other words: your onKey listener is handling way to much responsibilities. Refactor the calculation into a new class like:

```
class TypeRateCalculator(){
    private Date startTime;
    private Date elapsedTime;
    private int characterCount = 0;

    public void startMeasuring() {
        startTime = new Date();
    }

    public int updateTypingRate() {
        characterCount++;
        elapsedTime = new Date();
        long delta = (elapsedTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000 / 60;
        int typingRate = Math.max(0, (int) (characterCount/ delta ));
        return typingRate;
    }
}
```

Then call updateTypingRate() in your keyListener.

Finally: If an if-statement does the same as the else-statement, you can remove the whole branching and just do the stuff directly:

```
if (x) {
    foo();
}
else {
    foo();
}
```

is the same as:

```
foo()
```